# Display training records and results with graphics on multiple platforms?

Tags: web-apps, database

If I were doing this for work where we're all on fiber/Ethernet wires, I'd muddle up an Access database and drop it on a server.  But I'm totally over my head here, and haven't a clue which way to go.

We have various training activities.  There are videos of each activity, so two years from now we can remember what it looked like.  There are charts of results for each individual (like a spreadsheet or data table). And photos of the end results.

We need to get to a system that allows us to call up the data and display it across multiple platforms (Windows or Mac computers, Apple or Android tablets).  We need to see: (1) a training session view which has all participants, all trainings performed, and their scores; (2) a single person and their score history, including photos of results; (3) a single training module and any/all persons so trained within a span of time with their histories; (4) a single training event with all participants for that event with scored and photos .... And I'm sure someone will say "Can we look at it like this??"

On my computer or a work network, it's Access with tables and queries and forms.  Throw in the internet requirement with multiple devices, and I'm lost!  Can someone please drop-kick me in a god direction?  At least what kind of intelligent questions to ask to get to the right place?

Ed